# wp_insert_term doesn't work with custom post type's tax

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Here is the problem I am having:

```
I have a custom post type called "developer"
This custom post type "developers" has a custom taxonomy, "developer", hierarchic
I want to programmatically insert into this custom taxonomy "developer" 2 terms
```

Here is the function and the action I am using to insert one term:

```
// programatically add terms to the taxonomy "developer"
function autoset_post_developer(&$post, $developer)
{
    if(empty($developer)) return;
    $cat    = get_cat_ID($developer);
    if(!$cat)
    {
        $cat    = wp_insert_term($developer, 'developer', array(
            'description' => '' . $developer,
            'slug' => sanitize_title($developer)
        ));
        $cat    = $cat['term_id'];
    }
    if($cat)
    {
        $post['post_developer'] = array($cat);
    }
}
```

The problem: wp_insert_term doesn't appear to be working with my custom taxonomy

Comment: What's the custom post type is it `developers` or `developer` ?

Comment: register_taxonomy('developers'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is higher in your code.

```
$cat    = get_cat_ID($developer);
```

will return false for a custom taxonomy, as it only checks the standard categories.

Use [get_term_by](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by) instead.

Comment: give me  any example